# LNK1104 Error when adding Boost library to Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, boost, build-error

M'kay so I'm new to `Qt` and I'm trying to include the `boost/filesystem` lib to my project. However, when I try to build it, I always get this error:

> LNK1104: File "libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_61.lib" cannot be
>   opened.

Now, I know that this library needs to be build beforehand, so, as described on the Boost-Website I made:

```
bootstrap
.\b2
```

and it built just fine. I also used the Qt dialog to add the libary to my project, my .pro-file looks like this:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = ProjectName
TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    someclass.cpp \
    someclass2.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    someclass.h \
    someclass2.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/libarys -llibboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_61
else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/libarys -llibboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_61
else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/libarys -llibboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_61

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/boost
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/boost
```

Apparently, I did something wrong, but I can't figure out, WHAT exactly it is. The internet knows the problem, but it seems there's no "easy" solution to it.

Comment: If `libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-1_61.lib` exists in the librarys subfolder of your project make sure you are not mixing 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: Turned out, it didn't like the runtime-linking. The file was there and the bit-versions were also ok. Thanks for your time though.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, my project didn't like the lib-version.

I rebuilt my lib files:

```
>b2 --build-dir="destination/directory" toolset=msvc --build-type=complete link=static threading=multi --with-filesystem stage
```

Then, I used the library in

```
release/link-static/runtime-link-static/threading-multi/
```

Which is:

```
libboost_filesystem-vc140-mt-s-1_61
```

And re-ran qmake for the .pro-file. Then built and executed the application and the error is gone.